# Functions/Variables multi-dependency import (called multiple times to import)

Tags: bash

I have multiple bash scripts files.

```
base.sh
roles.sh
collect.sh
```

both `role.sh` and `collect.sh` import `base.sh`

I have another file `actions.sh` that imports(source) both `role.sh` and `collect.sh`

1. What happens with the functions, variables in `base.sh` ? (they are actually called for import twice)
2. How can I check if an import was done properly ?

Comment: Does import mean `source`?

Comment: yes source . /base.sh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source works just as if the lines from the file were copied exactly to where the source command is located. As such, all variables and functions will be defined twice, which might not matter since the last call is what you will get, unless you have something between `role` and `collect` which changes something - and that will be overridden.

For example if something in `base` behaves differently according to the environment, and the two scripts set different environments prior to sourcing, then that could cause unexpected behavior (the second source overrides).

Even if just so save overhead, you might wrap the entire `base` with:

```
[ -n "$BASE_IMPORT" ] && return

...
...

BASE_IMPORTED=1
```

so you can prevent double sourcing in the same environment (without explicitly un-setting the variable).

Comment: How can I check if an import is ok or failed ?

Comment: @user3541631 That is a full question of its on, and depends on what you mean by "failed". If the source is not supposed to give output, you can capture `stderr`: `res=$(source base.sh 2>&1)` and check if `$res` is empty or not to see if anything printed an error.

Comment: if the file is not found

Comment: @user3541631 Then `BASE_IMPORTED` would not be set, so you could test `[ -n "$BASE_IMPORT" ]` in the sourcing script.